Topological tensor product
Let $A$ and $B$ be topological abelian groups. Consider the following universal property for a pair $(P, \pi)$, where $P$ is a topological abelian group and $\pi: A \times B \to P$ is a jointly continuous bilinear map: Given any topological abelian group $C$ and any jointly continuous bilinear map $\mu: A \times B \to C$, there exists a unique continuous linear map $\varphi: P \to C$ with $\mu = \varphi \circ \pi$. In this case, write $A \otimes_\text{top} B = P$.
The first question: Given any two topological abelian groups $A$ and $B$, does there exist a topological abelian group $A \otimes_\text{top} B$ satisfying the universal property?
The second question: If $A$ and $B$ are complete with respect to the natural uniformities, is $A \otimes_\text{top} B$ also complete with respect to its natural uniformity?
